# Swift Firebase completion handler not working

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My code calls Firebase and gets user information and user images. Once that's loaded, the app populates an image field and a text label. At least, that's what's **supposed** to happen. But instead, I'm getting `fatal error: Index out of range` error. What am I missing?

Here's my code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var userImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var instructionsLabel: UILabel!
var currentUserName: String!

func loadExistingUsers(completion: @escaping () -> ()) {
    ref.child("members").observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in
        if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String : Any] {
            let userPhotoUrl = dict["profileImageUrl"] as! String
            let userFirstName = dict["firstName"] as! String
            let userBirthday = dict["birthday"] as! Int
            let userPasscode = dict["passcode"] as! Int
            let userGender = dict["gender"] as! String
            let isUserChildOrParent = dict["childParent"] as! String

            let storageRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference(forURL: userPhotoUrl)
            storageRef.data(withMaxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024, completion: { (data, error) in
                let pic = UIImage(data: data!)
                let user = User(profilePhoto: pic!,
                                userFirstName: userFirstName,
                                userBirthday: userBirthday,
                                userPasscode: userPasscode,
                                userGender: userGender,
                                isUserChildOrParent: isUserChildOrParent)
                self.users.append(user)
                self.users.sort(by: {$0.birthday < $1.birthday})
            })
            completion()
        }
    }
}
```

and my ViewDidLoad call:

```
loadExistingUsers {
        self.currentUserName = self.users[0].firstName   // error here
        self.instructionsLabel.text = "Choose daily and weekly job assignments for \(self.users[0].firstName)."
        self.userImage.image = self.users[0].photo
    }
```

What am I doing wrong? I know my base code is good because I've tested it. Is it just the completion handler that's the problem? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think that `childAdded` will be called the same moment someone is registering for your service. I think you should use that `value` to retrieve existing users from your firebase. (side note) avoid using implicit unwrapping `!`

Comment: Okay, but if I put `users.count` into the `ViewDidLoad` call, I'm getting a count of `0`, so I think something isn't loading properly. The data isn't loaded before the function gets called. Which is weird, because I have a completion handler `@escaping` right there. Thoughts?

Comment: The way you are appending data into the `users` array is not 100% correct. Keep in mind that you are making asynchronous call which means you will get any results until the callback is returned (in your case snapshot is return). So you would need transform your `completion` block to  `completion:@escaping(User->())` then you would be able to correctly append to your array. (also 0 is the same thing as empty if you are really think about, count == 0)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean when you say "the way you are appending data into the `users` array is not correct." Do you mean I should create a local variable within the function?

Comment: I added `completion: @escaping (User -> ())`, and I'm getting a syntax error. Did you mean `completion: @escaping ([User]) -> ()`?

Comment: Okay, so I got the syntax right, but now the function is returning the items incrementally [1,2,3,4], and so I can't iterate over them as a whole.

Comment: "the function is returning the items incrementally " because in `observe` you are using event type of `childAdded`, so this method is triggered for every child under members , in your case four times I guess